# Finding file size with c++

Tags: c++, printing, header, filenames, filesize

More problems, I'm genuinely confused, and it's bothering me to no end, I've tried almost everything with dirent.h as well. But here's an example of what I want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DataEventResponseMsg.idl"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "This is the size: " << sizeof(DataEventResponseMsg) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What that did was include that specific file and finds the size of it and prints it. I want to do that, but I need it to open a directory filled with .idl files and print which file it is and the size of it using sizeof..

I've tried to do it with dirent.h and opening the directory, and placing the contents into ent->d_name, and then looking for the sizeof the d_name and such, but all that does is print the size of the pointer.. and I tried placing the files into an array, but doing sizeof only prints the size of the array. I want it to print the sizeof the actual file as if I was including them in the header file like the one i posted..

Is this possible at all? I'm so confused and I need to get this to work, but I need help.

Please help.

EDIT ------

So I've done this with dirent.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
char FileArr[20][256];
DIR *dir;
FILE *fp;
int i = 0;
int k;
struct dirent *ent;

dir = opendir (argv[1]);
if( dir != NULL ){
    while(( ent = readdir ( dir ) ) != NULL ){
        strcpy( FileArr[i], ent->d_name );
        fp = fopen( FileArr[i], "rw" );
        cout << FileArr[i] << ", " << sizeof(FileArr[i]) << endl;
        fclose(fp);
        i++;
    }
    closedir( dir );
}
return 0;
}
```

And this opened up the directory from the command line, and it placed the contents into ent->d_name, and I copied those strings into an array and tried to find the size of all the contents in the array. However, doing sizeof only does the size of the array, of if i used a pointer, of the pointer. And I want to find the sizeof of the actual file, not anything that's holding the file string/name.

Comment: Use `stat(2)` to get a file size.

Comment: `sizeof` is not for this thing at all; `dirent.h` is somewhat in right direction. Take a look at `_stat / _stat64 / stat ...` (or `GetFileSizeEx` on Windows)

Comment: Can you please look at my edit? I've done something with dirent.h before but it just didn't work out the way I wanted it to..

Comment: Ok, now I see what you're trying to achieve.. Hmm, I don't think it is possible without parsing the files somehow. @chakolatemilk maybe you should edit the question title to something like "determine size of structs contained in files"

Comment: @lethal-guitar, yea, I was afraid of that.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lethal-guitar provided is a nice OS-independent way of getting the file sizes, so long as you already know what files are in a directory.  If you don't know what files are in a directory, then you're back to using platform-specific tools, for example, `dirent` for Linux, as you suggest.  Below is a trivial example of how to use `dirent`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct stat file_stats;
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent* dent;

    dirp=opendir("."); // list files in the current directory (replace with any other path if you need to)
    do {
        dent = readdir(dirp);
        if (dent)
        {
            printf("  file \"%s\"", dent->d_name);
            if (!stat(dent->d_name, &file_stats))
            {
                printf(" is size %u\n", (unsigned int)file_stats.st_size);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" (stat() failed for this file)\n");
            }
        }
    } while (dent);
    closedir(dirp);
}
```

Comment: Okay, so this works REALLY well. And it's ALMOST what I want.. But you see.. the .idl files that I'm trying to find the size of.. I'm trying to find the size of the struct, rather than the actual file bytes.. which is why I was using sizeof because the first code I posted in the topic above, it found the size of the struct of that specific .idl and it was 80.. And I want to be able to do that to the rest of the .idl files that I have.. A little weird, I know..

Comment: @chakolatemilk - What is a .idl file?  What's in it?

Comment: It's an interface definition file for OS Windows. In an idl, though, are just a 1 or 2 structs with about 3 or 4 variables in each. And when I use sizeof() on one, it should show the size of the structs rather than the size of the entire .idl in bytes.. I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: @chakolatemilk - You  can't use dirent() in conjunction with sizeof() to do this.  dirent() is a runtime function that reads a directory at runtime; sizeof() always resolves at compile-time to a constant.  Perhaps you can parse the .idl files’ contents to get the types of the variables in them, and then compute the size of each.  Alternatively, create a .cpp source file, one per .idl file, and use your #include and sizeof() constructs to display the sizes that way.  Your main() would need to call a function in each of the .cpp files to print the results for its corresponding .idl file.

Comment: @chakolatemilk - Though my code sample & answer weren't exactly what you needed, they do answer your question as stated, as they do give you the files & their sizes.  Hopefully my comments above were also helpful in guiding you toward the solution you actually need.  If you did find them helpful, please both upvote and select my answer.  If you need further assistance, let me know.

Comment: Aw. I was hoping I would be able to. There's 30+ .idl files in my folder, and it would be a hassle to do one for each .idl file..

Comment: Yes, your answer was the closest to what I wanted. Thanks so much for your help. :)

Comment: @chakolatemilk - Thanks for selecting it.  If you feel that I expended sufficient effort and was sufficiently helpful, please also upvote my answer.

Comment: Nice dirent example, but I found that when the path is not "." we need to use `stat(full_directory_path + "\\" + dent->d_name, &file_stats)` because "dent->d_name" is only file name without path. (tested on Windows)

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to get a file's size in C++. One way is to seek to the end of the file end then ask for the file pointer's position:

```
ifstream file("filename.idl", ios::in);
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
auto fileSize = file.tellg();
```

That is even given as an example on this page:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/

Besides that, there are other (OS-specific) solutions, like pointed out in the comments, but this approach should work regardless of your platform.

Comment: I know about this, and I've done this.. But what I'm trying to avoid is having to manually type every file inside the code.. I want the code to open a directory and look into each file and print out the file name and its size. :/